# necesito ayuda completar una idea que tengo para un patron MVC que pueda una url limpia

Tags: php

tengo el problema de que cuando trabajo con mvc la url se ve asi "?url=inicio&action=vista" me gustaria poder cambiarla por lo que hice lo siguiente

```
class Vista
```

{
private $vista;

```
public function getVista()
{
  return $this->vista;
}

function __construct()
{
  if (!isset($_GET['url']))
  {
    $this->vista = vista.'inicio-vista.php';
    return false;
  }

  $url = $_GET['url'];
  $action = $_GET['action']; 

  $url = rtrim($url, '/');
  $action = rtrim($action, '/');

  $archivo = vista.$url."-".$action.".php";

  if (file_exists($archivo))
  {
    $this->vista = $archivo;
  }
  else
  {
    $archivo = vista.$url."-".$action.".php";
    if (file_exists($archivo))
    {
      $this->vista = $archivo;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->vista = privado.'404-vista.php';
    }
  }

  }
}
```

pero creo que me falta desarrollarla mejor, por que al llamar el action me daba problemas o si no chocaba con la llamada a los controladores que lo hacia asi , usaba la variable url tambien pero entonces decia que action estaba vacia por lo que tuve cambiarla por la variable control

```
class Controlador
```

{
private $controlador;

```
public function __construct()
{
    return $this->controlador;
}

public function getControlador()
{
    return $this->controlador;
}

public function Controlador()
{
    if (!empty($_GET['control'])) {
        $control = $_GET['control'];
    } else {
        $control = "vistas";
    }

    if (is_file("controlador/" . $control . "-controlador.php")) {
        include_once "controlador/" . $control . "-controlador.php";
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Pero qué es lo que quieres conseguir, exactamente?

Comment: la verdad hacer un mvc con url amigables pero sigo sin poder hacerlo

Comment: jeje, por eso decía exactamente, es decir, que URL quieres manejar? estás tomando en cuenta el rewrite que tiene que hacer el servidor?